# Can't resize columns in grid

Tags: acumatica

I have several custom screens which have grids.  On all but one of them I can resize the columns.  In the one where I can't resize, I'm using BLC code to determine when to hide the column and what to display as the name of the column.  I do this as follows:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<xTACOpenSourceDetail.string03>(OpenSourceDataDetail.Cache, null, true);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<xTACOpenSourceDetail.string03>(this.OpenSourceDataDetail.Cache, ossd.String03);
```

All my grids are set up the same way, except for this one difference.  Is there an attribute or property I can set to make sure these columns are sizable as well?

Comment: If you remove those two line of codes, does the problem persist? I think something else is going on.

Comment: I can't remove them - they're integral to how the whole grid renders itself.  Every field has conditional visibility and display text.   Is there any property or attribute I can modify to ensure the ability to resize the grid columns?

Comment: I think you have a good approach in trying to determine the difference between the grid that are working and the one that isn't but I question the conclusion that these 2 lines of code are the difference that breaks the grid. Removing them seems the right way to verify this hypothesis. I don't see what problem it would cause to test the grid without code, you could comment out the whole graph just to be sure. Seeing the ASPX code would likely be more helpful in trying to replicate the issue. I don't know of a property that prohibits column resizing.

Comment: Either removing differences one by one or starting from scratch using a working grid as the base and slowly re-integrating the changes would be good way to identify the breaking change.

Comment: Another thing I would check first is whether or not browser used and webpage zoom level are affecting the behavior of the column resizing mechanism.

Comment: Actually there is a property for column resizing but it's set to True as default: <px:PXGridColumn  AllowResize="False"/>

Comment: I've commented everything in the BLC except the view definitions.  Makes no difference.  This is bizarre.  All my other custom grids allow resizing.

Comment: That's a good start, if the root cause isn't in the back end (BLC) then it's likely in the front end (ASP). Can you add your page ASPX code to your answer?

Comment: Also add the view definitions just in case if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dissecting this for a while, The solution I've come up with was to re-create the entire screen from scratch.  This corrected the issue, and I can only conclude that something became corrupted within the original screen and could not be refreshed or recompiled.  It is still unknown what caused the issue to begin with.